# Unable to call Handle Cast function in a Genserver from the same module using it's own API

Tags: elixir, gen-server

I am trying to call the handle_cast function in a GenServer from it's own API. However, the handle_cast function doesn't seem to be getting called. I have put debug statements to understand where it is breaking.

Debug 5 gets printed but Debug 4 is not getting printed.

Note: The `done()` function is being called from another `GenServer`.

```
# Public API
def done(pid) do
  GenServer.cast(__MODULE__, {:done, pid})
  IO.puts("Debug 5")
end

#Server
def handle_cast({:done, pid}, {num, startTime, nbor_map}) do
  IO.puts("Debug 4")
  if num <= 1 do
    IO.puts("Time taken:")
    end_time = System.monotonic_time(:millisecond)
    time_taken = end_time - startTime
    IO.inspect(time_taken)
    System.halt(0)
  end

  {:noreply, {num - 1, startTime, nbor_map}}
end
```

Also, I am not getting any compilation errors. Can someone suggest why the `handle_cast` function is not getting called or why "Debug 4" is not getting printed?

Comment: Please show how you start the process (`GenServer.start_link` call or like.) It seems you did not assign a name to the process.

Answer (score 0):

Your start_link should look something like

```
  def start_link(opts) do
    GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, opts, name: __MODULE__)
  end
```

The name: option is for [name registration of the server](http://%20https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/GenServer.html#start_link/3-options).